# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to get value from radioButton (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a string value from radioButton, but when I try it shows this error on LogCat. I can't seem to figure how to fix it..these are the codes :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle konsumsi) {
        super.onCreate(konsumsi);
        radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
        setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
        usernameP = Login.usernameP;
        System.out.println(usernameP);

        buttonDone();

    }
public void buttonDone() {
        selesai = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProses);
        selesai.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int selectedId = radioAktivitasGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();     
                    radioAktivitasButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    String Aktivitas = radioAktivitasButton.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }
```

the errors :

```
    05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ta.nutrifact/com.ta.nutrifact.AktivitasUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at com.ta.nutrifact.AktivitasUser.onCreate(AktivitasUser.java:71)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-20 07:01:07.858: E/AndroidRuntime(3179):     ... 11 more
```

I did exactly the same on the other class and it's working but not on this one. ANy help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: also what is  `Login.usernameP;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the statements

```
 radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
 setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
 radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);// null pointer boz you call it before initialize xml file.
  setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user); //set layout first 
radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
```

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
```

Like,

```
setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
    radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
    setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
```

to

```
    // this right way to do
    setContentView(R.layout.aktivitas_user);
    radioAktivitasGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAktivitasGroup);
```

Null pointer exception shown because you initialize view before layout add.

Answer (score 0):

use setContentView first, and then findViewById